# Sharepoint 2010 convert text into date

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-online, sharepoint-server, calculated-column, calculated-column-formula

I’m trying to convert a column type “Choice (3/29/17) (4/29/17)” into a date  using the code below and get a “#Value!” error in Calculated column

```
=TEXT(DATE(LEFT(CounselingDT,4),MID(CounselingDT,6,2),RIGHT(CounselingDT,2)),"dd-mm-yyyy")
```

Answer (score 3):

Try the below formula:

```
=TEXT(DATE(YEAR([CounselingDT]),MONTH([CounselingDT]),DAY([CounselingDT])),"dd-mm-yyyy")
```

**OutPut**

[image]

Comment: Hello, Thank you for your response, I tried the formula, it converted CalColumn to date but as soon as I tab to next column, the CalColumn change it value to #VALUE!

Comment: the calculated field will not be applied until you add a new item or update the current item, Please Mark my answer in case it solved your issue :) Thanks

Comment: Still getting #VALUE! after inputting the CalDate.

Comment: Example post above work on Standard view, not on Datasheet view.

Comment: bro, you didn't mention this in your question? you just asked about the formula !!

Comment: while the formula is working properly as I show in my screen shoot at the standard view and should working properly in datasheet view !!